# unknown directive "geoip_country" on nginx/1.10.1

Tags: nginx, geoip

I have  a nginx/1.10.1 on my CentOS 7 installed via nginx repo. I just install geoip module

```
[root@www nginx]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic **--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic** --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --add-dynamic-module=njs-1c50334fbea6/nginx --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

Added `geoip_country GeoIP.dat;` to http section on `nginx.conf`, but when I am doung configtest

```
[root@www nginx]# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "geoip_country" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dynamic modules must be explicitly loaded from the `main` section of the nginx configuration.

```
 load_module "modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";
```

Comment: hmm, where should i add that line of code ? :)

Comment: @AttilaNaghi It must be placed in the `main` block.

Comment: I thought so, I tried, but still doesn't work. Not sure sure what I am missing :(

Comment: see my post: https://serverfault.com/questions/1001671/how-can-i-install-the-ngx-http-geoip2-module-module-on-centos for details. If you have time , please take a look. Thnx in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution Michael proposed works the underlying problem is that nginx does not properly (sufficiently) load the modules from the */etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*. Likely due to the wrong scope where these modules are loaded from.

Much better, permanent solution is to add this line to nginx.conf:

```
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*;
```

Comment: After upgrading an older version on CentOS 7, I found the module configurations available at `/usr/share/nginx/modules/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
file /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip.conf
```

when ASCII text file is exist

```
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip.conf /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/mod-http-geoip.conf
```

and then service nginx start

done