# How can I install the ngx_http_geoip2_module module ? on Centos

Tags: nginx, geoip

I installed the GeoIP package using yum. I got the geoIP files in the `/usr/share/GeoIP/` folder. I need to add some rules on some countries in the: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and to do that i need to load the module, like: `load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so;`, to recognize  the variables. See:

`geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;`

So how can i install this module?  I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module/blob/master/README.md#installing and the url is outdated or invalid, not sure, but i cannot download it . Also I already have nginx being installed. Any suggestions? thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

please download the [ngx_http_geoip2_module](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module) by clicking on the "Code" button.

Unzip it.

Assume it is unzipped at `/home/someuser/ngx_http_geoip2_module-master`.

Pass this location to `--add-dynamic-module` of `./configure`:

```
./configure --add-dynamic-module=/home/someuser/ngx_http_geoip2_module-master
```

then follow the remaining instructions.